# Autocomplete jQuery from MySQL not working

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel view page and getting data from a DB using jQuery. I have other functions working fine but I am not able to see what I am doing wrong here. It returns an empty field.

I am enclosing code snippets for blade, controller, `web.php`, `default.js`.

Help me please :)

```js
/* default.js*/
$( ".search_doc_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/search/doc_name",
  minLength: 1,
  response: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.content.length === 0) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
      $(this).next().removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');

      $(".search_doc_name_empty").show();
      $('.form_submit').hide();
    } else {
      $(".search_doc_name_empty").hide();
      $('.form_submit').show();
    }
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('.search_doc_id').val(ui.item.id);
    $('.search_doc_name').val(ui.item.value);
  }
});

$( ".search_doc_name" ).on('keyup',function(){
   $(".search_doc_name_empty").hide();
});
```

```php
/*And this is my controller :*/
public function doc_name(Request $request){
  $term = $request['term'];
  $input = $request->all();

  $results = array();

  $queries = \App\Models\DoctorsDetail::where('doc_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->take(25)->get();

  foreach ($queries as $key => $value)
    {
       $queries[$key]['value'] = $value->doc_name;
    }

    return \Response::json($queries);
}
```

```php
/* web.php*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'search'], function () {
  Route::any('/doc_name', 'SearchController@doc_name');
});
```

```
/*blade*/
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>اسم الدكتور</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control search_doc_name"  placeholder="Type here ..." name="doc_name">
      <span class="help-block search_doc_name_empty" style="display: none;">No Results Found ...</span>
      <input type="hidden" class="search_doc_id" name="doc_id">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Whats the response it is bringing? An error? Empty data?

Comment: it is Empty Data, like it is a normal text form control not having a class linking it to JQuery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolved itself after clearing the cache. Suddendly started working